# Creating an special jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to make a function that moves an element to the selected position:

I want it to look like this:

```
$('#drag').jDrag.moveTo(233, 1);
```

As it will be an api for my plugin.

My code is:

```
$.jDrag = function () {};
$.fn.jDrag.moveTo = function (x, y) {
    $(this).animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: x,
        top: y
    });
};
```

The code is breaking my plugin. I know why, because its wrong. But I dont know how else to do it. I'm using the `$.jDrag = function () {};` to get the `jDrag` part in the api function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That can't work, because `this` will get lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with some minor modifications, you can do this

```
    $.fn.jDrag = function(opt){

    if(opt.moveTo)
    {
        var x = opt.moveTo.x, y = opt.moveTo.y
        $(this).animate({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: x,
            top: y
        });
    }

};
```

So the final is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
      $('#some').jDrag({moveTo:{x:233, y:1}});
});
```